# Html padding-top

Tags: html, css

I have this image.[work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nktDJ.jpg)

and I need to do this one in HTML and CSS. I did, here s my code

```css
.one{
 color: #1E90FF;
 text-align: left;
}
.two{
 color: #1E90FF;
}
.three{
float: right;
border: 1px blue solid;
margin-right: 5px;

}
.clear{
 clear: both;
}

.pag{
 padding-left: 15px;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>No</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="aka.css">
</head>
 <body>
  <h3 class="one">Пять доводов в пользу Греции: Крит, Санторини, Родос, Корфу и Кос</h3>
  <p><img src="images/picture3.jpg" class="three "></p>
             <p class=" pag">Современных туристов 
                   мифами не удивишь, поэтому Греция всесторонне развивает 
                   инфраструктуру туризма на материковой и островной территориях. 
                   О перспективах и потенциале греческого направления в 
                   преддверии горячего сезона рассказывает Дмитрий АРУТЮНОВ, 
                   генеральный директор компании «Арт-тур».<span class="two">>>></span></p>
                   <br class="clear"><br><br>
<img src="images/picture1.jpg" class="three">
 <h3 class="one">Модные тенденции в туризме: вклюЧАЙ фестиваль</h3>
             <p class="pag">Человек в год выпивает в 
                   среднем 150 литров чая. Несмотря на внушительный возраст чая, 
                   причины высокой популярности этого напитка остаются загадкой и 
                   по сей день. Чтобы узнать их и разобраться до конца в том, что 
                   же такое чай, как и когда его пить, команда Foresta Tropicana 
                   Hotel решила провести «ВклюЧАЙ фестиваль» - добрый семейный 
                   праздник за чашечкой чая. <span class="two">>>></span></p>
                   
                   <br class="clear">
 <p><img src="images/picture2.jpg" class="three"></p>
 <h3 class="one">10 правил выбора тура в Грецию</h3>
             <p class="pag">У каждого из нас есть 
                   любимый фотоальбом, в котором хранятся фотографии, 
                   напоминающие о самых ярких моментах нашей жизни. И, конечно 
                   же, в этом альбоме, есть хроника наших путешествий. Как 
                   здорово, пролистать его снова и снова и еще раз окунуться в 
                   свои впечатления о веселых каникулах и пофантазировать о 
                   предстоящем отпуске!<span class="two">>>></span></p>
                   <br><br class="clear">
 <p><img src="images/picture4.jpg" class="three"></p>
 <h3 class="one">Марокко на любой вкус</h3>
             <p class="pag">Растущая популярность 
                   марокканского направления среди российских туристов вполне 
                   объяснима – природа, великолепный климат и пляжи Атлантики 
                   (воздух с высоким содержанием йода), большой выбор отелей с 
                   развитой инфраструктурой на лучшем курорте побережья в городе 
                   Агадир. Наиболее престижные гостиницы – Dorint Atlantic Palace 
                   5*, Palais des Roses 5*, Agadir Beach Club 4*, Riu Tikida 
                   Dunas 4*, Iberostar 4*.<span class="two">>>></span></p>
 </body>
</html>
```

(site is Russian, never mind.) I think I did it, you see any differences? I see only 1. I don t need to have indent from h3 to p. padding 0px doesn't work. what can I do in this situation? so I did all I could. and I cant do this. is this only one difference? u see more? help me, please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you have some margin issues that is why padding is not working.

do something like this:

```
h3, p {margin: 0;}
```